# AWS Xray Integration in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, aws-xray

Been on this integration for a while now, I have managed to get only segment working,

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as AWSXray from "aws-xray-sdk";


const port = config.get<string>('PORT') || 8081;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(AWSXray.express.openSegment('app'));
  AWSXray.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http'));
  app.use(AWSXray.express.closeSegment());


  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);


}
bootstrap();
```

My outgoing modules on HTTP modules are not showing on the trace map.

Answer (score 1):

The X-Ray Node SDK does not support NextJS instrumentation out of the box. The express instrumentation captures outgoing requests and responses using `openSegment` and `closeSegment` middleware to wrap routes. [`OpenSegment` should be added *before all routes are defined*, and `closeSegment` should be added *after all routes are defined*](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/express#middleware-usage).

```
import * as AWSXray from "aws-xray-sdk";

const AWS = AWSXRay. captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'));
app.use(AWSXray.express.openSegment('app'));

// create routes

app.use(AWSXray.express.closeSegment());
```

There are a few simple examples on setting up the express instrumentation in the [aws-xray-sdk-express documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/express#automatic-mode-example), as well as a sample application that includes a more involved setup with [capturing outgoing http requests](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-sdk-node-sample/blob/master/index.js#L9-L19) that can be used as a guide (or ran locally for testing)